# Hibernate PersistentList has data, but returns null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `PersistentList` of `myEntity` objects, and the list shows a size of 8. The objects look good through the debugger, and I'm within a Hibernate Session and Transaction. However, when I iterate through it, null is returned for all the objects.

```
 for(MyEntity myEntity : myEntities){
            //myEntity is null
 }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it might be because of lazy loading. You see the size as 8 but the objects are not actually loaded from the memory yet.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that at first, but I was within a Hibernate Session, so it should have fetched the data when it needed to. Please see my answer above.

Answer (score -1):

It actually turned out to be related to an `Ordinal` column, and it's `base` was out of sync.

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/hibernate-why-are-there-nulls-in-my-collection/